# Run code while readline is waiting for input?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to take "optional" input using readline, but I'm unsure of how I can allow code to run "in the background" while readline is awaiting input. I can't really find anything on it by searching, but then I may be searching for the wrong thing.

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Options:\n [1] Files processed (total)\n [2] Files processed (session)', function(answer) => {

});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to database");

    fs.watch(basedir, (event, filename) => {
        if(filename && filetype.includes(getType(filename))) {
            console.log("Found file with type: " + getType(filename));
            if(getType(filename) == "zip") {

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Essentially, I want the question available the entire time, while running the con.connect method continuously at the same time

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing your actual code and what you're trying to do.  node.js is generally event driven so you can do anything else you want with your code while waiting for an event to happen.  Since it appears you may be new here, you should know that questions about code must include that relevant code in the question.  We are very good at helping you sort out problems with your specific code.  We are not good at answering hypothetical questions that contain no code.

Comment: Just listen on `stdin`. Its actually more difficult to do this kind of thing in a blocking way.

Comment: I've added some code to sort of show what I'm trying to do, but I don't have any functional code for what I'm trying to do